# Airflow tasks' priority not honored

Tags: airflow

I have a dag similar to this:

```py
with DAG(..., concurrency=3) as dag:
   important = [ op1, op2, op3, ... ]
   less_important=[ opA, opB, opC, ... ]
   important >> DummyOperator('Important', priority_weight=1000)
   less_important >> DummyOperator('LessImportant', priority_weight=1)
```

The idea is to use the default `weight rule` being `WeightRule.DOWNSTREAM` to ensure that the `important` tasks are scheduled before the `less_important` ones.

Inspecting the task instance details I see that the priorities for the `important` and `less_important` tasks are correctly computed (1001 and 2, resp.).
However, the last run scheduled one of the `less_important` tasks right away, next to two of the `important` ones.

Am I overlooking something?

Oh, I'm using Airflow v. 1.8.0. I checked the changelog and I don't see any ticket regarding weight and priority, so I don't suppose it's something that was fixed, but I might of course be wrong.

Comment: I also observed that tasks are not scheduled according to their priority weights (in airflow 1.9.0). I guess the scheduler also uses queued time to decide whether to run a task.

Comment: I have since upgraded to 1.10.x and it is fixed there :)